# How do I size an image as large as possible, but not so large that it causes the parent div to grow in height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

My code below is taken nearly verbatim from the example at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#media-object. It should create a box with a picture on the left and some text on the right:

```
<div class="mycard border border-dark m-3 p-3 d-flex align-items-center" style="width: 33%;">
  <div class="flex-shrink-0">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.sidsavage.com/images/prods/popup/P8889.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-3">
    This is some content from a media component. You can replace this with any content and adjust it as needed.
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the catch: the image I used is really huge, which causes the box to become messed up. I could fix this by adding `style="max-height: 70px;"` to the img tag, but I don't know in advance how big to make the image. I want the text to dictate the height of the box, and the image to be sized appropriately for that box height.

You can play with my example here: https://codepen.io/Meekro/pen/oNQGMPM

Comment: `width: 100%` seems to do the job on its own, as long as you get rid of `flex-shrink: 0` on the parent. Maybe set a min-width on the container, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using columns to make the space for the image and using
`background-size: contain` to keep the image within the boundaries of the container div might work for you.

See sample code below

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2" id="forImg" style='background: white url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.sidsavage.com/images/prods/popup/P8889.jpg") no-repeat center;
   background-size: contain;'>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-10">
      <p class="card-text">
      This is some content from a media component. You can replace this with any content and adjust it as needed.
    </p>
  <p class="card-text">
      This is some content from a media component. You can replace this with any content and adjust it as needed.
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that jQuery `<script>` is a mistake?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't seem to work. The image is still way too big, and it's still making the box look broken and increasing its height. Remember, my goal is for the box to have the same height as it would have without the image.

Comment: let me see if I got it right this time... trick was to use the image as a background (but I am still unsure this still does what you'd like)

Answer (score 0):

In pure css you can just add a width to your image:

```
style="max-width:100%;"
```

height will automatically calculate.  If you know the dimensions it's best to use aspect-ratio to prevent repaints/recalculations.

```
style="max-width:100%;aspect-ratio:4/3;"
```

Where 4/3 is your known aspect ratio.

**EDIT**: I didn't read the height part of your question lol.

If the parent has a set height, just do:

```
style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%;"
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. "max-height" as a percentage does not work where the parent doesn't have an explicitly set height. You can see this for yourself by clicking the codepen link and editing the example with your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said if the parent has a height you can set max-height:100%;